# How to convert numeric value in English to Marathi numeric value in C#?

Tags: c#

I am developing an windows application in C#, for that I need to convert English numeric value to Marathi numeric value. For Example. "123" = "१२३"

Comment: Do you know the `Marathi numeric value` `unicode` values? http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec Checkout the `go to other block` ComboBox in that side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obviose way is use [`String.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts(v=vs.110).aspx) method and write helper class.

```
public class MarathiHelper
{
    private static Dictionary<char, char> arabicToMarathi = new Dictionary<char, char>()
    {
      {'1','१'},
      {'2','२'},
      {'3','३'},
      {'4','४'},
      {'5','५'},
      {'6','६'},
      {'7','७'},
      {'8','८'},
      {'9','९'},
      {'0','०'},
    };

    public static string ReplaceNumbers(string input)
    {
        foreach (var num in arabicToMarathi)
        {
            input = input.Replace(num.Key, num.Value);
        }
        return input;
    }

}
```

And in your code you can use it like this:

```
var marathi = MarathiHelper.ReplaceNumbers("123");
```

`marathi` will have `"१२३"`

Answer (score 2):

Well, in order to convert every character in `['0'..'9']` should be shifted by `0x0966 - '0'`; and the implementation could be

```
  string source = "The number is 0123456789";

  string result = new String(source
    .Select(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9' ? (Char) (c - '0' + 0x0966) : c)
    .ToArray());
```

The outcome (`result`) is

```
  The number is ०१२३४५६७८९
```

Note, that `Char.IsDigit(c)` is not an option here, since we don't want to shift Marathi numbers